# How can I append a CSV file to an existing zip archive in Python?

Tags: python, django, csv, django-rest-framework, zip

I am calling an API which returns a zip file back. Before sending this to the client for download, I want to append a csv file I'm creating to it. Below is how I am creating the CSV and my attempt at appending it, but I get what's seemingly an endless nested zip file that keeps appending the number `2` to the file name. It seems Mac OS is endlessly converting it from a zip to a cpgz and back again. If I try to run `unzip` on this file, I get the following error

> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>     a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
>     latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>     the last disk(s) of this archive.

Code to generate CSV in memory

```
transactions_csv = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(transactions_csv, fieldnames=all_parsed_transactions[0].keys())
writer.writeheader()
for transaction in all_parsed_transactions:
    writer.writerow(transaction)

return transactions_csv
```

Code attempting to append to existing zip

```
export = io.ByesIO(request.export_data()) #This is a zip response
transaction_csv = request.export_transactions() #This calls the code above

if transaction_csv is not None and export is not None:
    new_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(export, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    new_zip.write("test.csv", transaction_csv.getvalue())
    new_zip.close()

    return HttpResponse(new_zip, content_type='application/zip')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first look it seems that

```py
export = request.export_data()
```

returned byte data. ZipFile only works with file-like objects, could you, please, try wrapping it up with:

```py
export = io.BytesIO(request.export_data())
export.seek(0) # this sets cursor to the beginning of file
# I had some issues with cursors not being at the beginning of the file 
# and thus data read from it was corrupt.
```

UPD: there are actually more problems than I described. Will be back shortly.

Here is full working example:

```py
import csv
import io
import zipfile


transactions = [
    {"f1": 1, "f2": 2, "f3": 3},
    {"f1": 3, "f2": 1, "f3": 2},
    {"f1": 2, "f2": 3, "f3": 1},
]


transactions_csv = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(transactions_csv, fieldnames=["f1", "f2", "f3"])
writer.writeheader()
for transaction in transactions:
    writer.writerow(transaction)
transactions_csv.seek(0)

with open("file.zip", "r+b") as z:
    new_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(z, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False)
    new_zip.writestr("transaction3.csv", transactions_csv.read())
    new_zip.close()
```

NOTE: I'm using file-like objects everywhere, assuming that this is one of the main problems. Code will be much simplier if you had your zip.file saved on disk.

Comment: It looks like this is just creating a CSV and adding it to a brand new zip file. As stated in the question, I need to add this CSV to an existing zip file. I cannot write to disk as this is a DRF API I'm building, and will be called by the JavaScript frontend to download the actual file. I've got a bit further with your original suggestion, I'm going to update my question with where I am now. I'm just getting weird nested zip files returned to the frontend now with `2` repeated over and over, looks like corrupted data

Comment: I was able to put a `new_zip.extractall()` in my code to look at the zip on the server and it works! Looks like my frontend was what was causing the issues. Thanks for your first answer, it got me past a wall and I was able to figure out the rest.